# Identify if IO bottleneck is read or write

Tags: files, io, disk-image, defragmentation

I use `ddrescue` to image failing disk to sparse files - often the files become highly fragmented (>50k fragments).

I suspect that sometimes the imaging speed degrades because of the fragmentation. Is there way to detect if the slowness is because of the read to the source disk or the write to the target file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `ddrescue` is reading from one block device and writing to another. You can run `iostat -xyh 10` to find out how much data is being read/written/discarded per second on each block device (number of reads/writes/discards as well as the amount of data read/written/discarded).

Example output from a laptop with one SSD:

```
$ iostat -xyh /dev/nvme0n1 10
Linux 5.4.0-26-generic (tux)        05/16/2020      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)


avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          16.3%    0.0%   34.7%    9.3%    0.0%   39.6%

     r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz Device
    0.60      9.6k     0.00   0.0%    1.17    16.0k nvme0n1

     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz Device
 2422.60    294.7M     0.40   0.0%   11.41   124.5k nvme0n1

     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz Device
    0.00      0.0k     0.00   0.0%    0.00     0.0k nvme0n1

  aqu-sz  %util Device
   23.25  34.3% nvme0n1
```

It's quite obvious from these numbers that I was heavily writing to my SSD while there were almost no read operations. You might also want to keep an eye on the iowait time related to reads ("r_await") and writes ("w_await").

Refer to the [iostat man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iostat.1.html) for details.

Comment: I think `ddrescue` runs synchronously: read (lets say) 64k then write, so the rates are mostly equal (when I check with `iotop`) and I can't tell where the bottleneck is.

Comment: True but I would expect to see higher await times for the slower driver.